# change random button text C#

Tags: c#, variables

I am trying to make a random button change its text based on a random number. I have tried the following code:

```
if (Button(random int 1 to 9)).Text != "X")
{
    MessageBox.Show("test worked");
}
```

Any input on how I could do this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an array or list of `Button`s, and add each button to it, and select one randomly, or name each button `ButtonX`, where X is the number. You can then use [`Find()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28VS.80%29.aspx) to select a button by it's name.

Example:

```
Random random = new Random();

if ((this.Controls.Find("Button" + random.Next(1, 10).ToString())
    .First() as Button).Text != "X")
{
     MessageBox.Show("test worked");
}
```

Make sure you create the `Random` instance outside of a method if it is called multiple times, as the result will not change.

Comment: @user266929 this is actually a more pure method of finding controls in C#. I would recommend using this.

Comment: I am using this solution now as the other suggestion will cause a stackoverflow error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
var rnd = new Random();

if(this.Controls["Button" + rnd.Next(1,10)].Text != "X")
{
    MessageBox.Show("test worked");
}
```

Ofcourse I'm assuming this is `WinForms` and you have at least 9 button in your `Form` named `Button1` to `Button9`...